# Как в ссылке заменить атрибут href на другой и закодировать путь в Base64

Tags: javascript, html, base64

Имеется несколько ссылок, ведущих на разные внешние страницы

```
<a class="button" href="https://site.ru/dsfssg">Ссылка</a>
```

Имея класс `"button"`, как закодировать содержимое `HREF` в `Base64` и после кодировки заменить атрибут `href` на придуманный атрибут `link`
Ссылки при этом должны иметь на выходе приблизительно вот такой вид

```
<a class="button" link="aHR0cHM6Ly9zaXRlLnJ1L2RzZnNzZw==">Ссылка</a>
```

и работать как ссылка, то-бишь при клике на нее переходишь на ту страницу, которая закодирована.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> как закодировать содержимое HREF в Base64 и после кодировки заменить атрибут href на придуманный атрибут link

Предложу вот такой вариант...

```js
const o = document.querySelector('.button')
let v = o.href
o.removeAttribute('href')
v = btoa(v)
o.setAttribute('link', v)
o.addEventListener('click', e => {
  let v = e.target.getAttribute('link')
  v = atob(v)
  location.href = v
})
```

```css
.button {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<a class="button" href="https://site.ru/dsfssg">Ссылка</a>
```

Comment: Вообще лучше делегирование событий использовать, т.к. в вопросе указанно, что ссылок должно быть несколько, а добавлять по несколько обработчиков идея такая себе.

Comment: @ΝNL993 Спасибо огромное, ссылок на странице будет 6, не сильная нагрузка будет?

Comment: @Arcadiy нет, не думаю что будет сильная нагрузка при всего лишь 6 ссылках. Но если ссылок планируется больше, то лучше всё-таки использовать делегирование событий и не ставить обработчик на каждую ссылку.

Comment: @ΝNL993 Спасибо огромное!

Comment: @Arcadiy не за что! Если что, вот ссылка на статью про [делегирование событий](https://learn.javascript.ru/event-delegation).

Comment: @ΝNL993 Спасибо!!!